# Are Opera 26 and Selenium-server-standalone jar 2.44.0 compatible?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, opera

Is Opera version 26 compatible with Selenium-server-standalone jar 2.44.0?

Comment: See https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver (I'm not sure about the selenium version requirements, but please try it out and post your findings here).

Comment: OperaDriver is available only up to Opera version 12 or below. Selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0 jar is compatible with version 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OperaDriver is available only up to Opera version 12.x or below. Selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0 jar is compatible with version 12.16 which happened to be the one which I tried my test on.